# COUNTIFS including entire column rather than one single item

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, countif, vba

Goal: To run a COUNTIFS matching Sheet2!A:A to Sheet1!B:B and a completed status from sample below. The goal is for sheet 1 to have training information pulled from a database and then I need to calculate who from that database has completed a list of specific training items (listed on sheet 2).

I have tried to set up a COUNTIFS but can only do it for each individual training item. I would have to set up a long string of these adding up and also include a user condition for the formula to work properly.

`COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B,**Sheet2!A2**,Sheet1!C:C,"complete")`

To save me a lot of time and potential errors, I would like to to run:

`COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B,**Sheet2!A:A**,Sheet1!C:C,"complete")`

However, when I enter the formula it displays an error. I also have tried to utilize pivot tables but it will not allow me to complete a COUNTIFS as a calculated field for the table. 
I am open to using VBA, but have limited experience in it if that will solve my issue.

Sheet 1:

```
Name    LO ID/Title Status
user 1    LO 1      complete
user 1    LO 2      complete
user 1    LO 3      registered
user 2    LO 1      complete
user 2    LO 3      complete
user 2    LO 4      complete
```

Sheet 2:

```
Cirricula
LO 1
LO 3
LO 4
```

EDIT: Ideal output on Sheet 2:

**User 1 - 1** (because they only have LO1 complete, LO2 is not required in the cirricula, and LO3 is a registered status)

**User 2 - 3** (because they have all three items complete required in the cirricula)

Comment: Can you put up a sample of what your output will look like? Will it be a `count` next to each `Cirricula` of how many `complete` statuses there are for that Cirricula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves manual selection (to exclude `LO 2`) of the `LO ID/Title` filter (unless set with VBA for example) but seems to give the results required:

[image: SO27027641 example]

Comment: Of course this is the best way to do it I think +1.

Comment: Yep I use them more than VBA for my clients dashboards and other useful and cool stuff :)

Comment: Thank you! So simple I didn't even think about filters.

Answer (score 0):

On Sheet 2, column B you can use

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7=A2)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7="complete"))
```

which will give as output

```
Cirricula   Count complete
LO 1            2
LO 3            1
LO 4            1
```

**Update / Edit**

To reference the `user`, just reference Column A in stead of Column B (or whereever your `user` column is):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=D2)*(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7="complete"))
```

Here on Sheet 2 I have `User` in column `D`

```
Cirricular  count cirricular complete       User    counter user complete
LO 1                2                       user 1          2
LO 2                1                       user 2          3
LO 4                1
```

**Update / Edit 2**

To get what you want using formula, I have included a `vlookup` in Column C to see if the `LO ID` is in the required list of `LO ID`s. You can then add this third criteria in the `sumproduct` formula.

(The `vlookup` in Column C is `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$F$2:$F$4,1,FALSE)),"no","yes")`)

[image: sumproduct]

Comment: Can this be modified to count by user and not cirricula?

Comment: Although this gives a different result given your edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your data like this:

[image]

Note that the LO List is in Sheet2. Enter this formula in F2:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$7,E2,B$2:B$7,Sheet2!A$2:A$4,C$2:C$7,"complete"))`

Above formula will give you the result you described above.
Not far from what I posted earlier, we just added another criteria range and criteria.
In short, you only need to incorporate *SUMPRODUCT* 
in your *COUNTIFS* formula when dealing with multiple criteria.

**Note:**
Your formula above is just lacking *SUMPRODUCT* and the other criteria for the **user** although I don't recommend using the entire column as criteria since it will hurt Excel's calculation time. Your best bet if your data is dynamic is to use a [*Dynamic Named Range*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287) for the multiple criteria. HTH.